# Show content if $scope.displayMsg is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this piece of code in AngularJS/Javascript:

```
var currBrowser = deviceDetector.browser,
    currBrowserVersion = deviceDetector.browser_version;

switch (currBrowser) {
    case 'chrome':
        if (parseInt(currBrowserVersion) <= 43) {
            $scope.displayMsg = true;
        }
        break;
    case 'safari':
        if (parseInt(currBrowserVersion) <= 8) {
            $scope.displayMsg = true;
        }
        break;
    case 'ie':
        if (parseInt(currBrowserVersion) <= 11) {
            $scope.displayMsg = true;
        }
        break;
    case 'firefox':
        if (parseInt(currBrowserVersion) <= 39) {
            $scope.displayMsg = true;
        }
        break;
    default:
        $scope.displayMsg = true;
        break;
}

console.log('browser' + currBrowser);
console.log('browser version' + currBrowserVersion);
console.log('displayMsg' + $scope.displayMsg);
```

Lets said that `currBrowser` is `chrome` and `currBrowserVersion` is `"43.0.2357.81"` (note double quotes here, this, I think, is a string). I want to display a message on the view only if `$scope.displayMsg` is `true` so I wrote this on the view:

```
<div ng-if="displayMsg == 'true'">Display something here</div>
```

But text isn't displayed at view. The `console.log()` show this:

```
browser chrome
browser version 43.0.2357.81
displayMsg true
```

Apparently message should be shown, why is not? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are comparing a string with a boolean, removing the `'` from the true should do the trick too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$scope.displayMsg` is a boolean value, the expression `displayMsg == 'true'` will always evaluate to false because you are comparing it to a string `'true'`.

You should only need to have:

```
<div ng-if="displayMsg">Display something here</div>
```